# Notebook for work and fun

Tags: gaming, laptop, development

I work with software development and have some games that I want to play. Games like The Witcher 3, Diablo 3: RoS, etc.

I live in a hot country, so I need something that won't overheat.

Requirements:

- Windows 7/8/10
- 2GB VRAM
- At least 8GB RAM
- 750GB to 2TB storage (SSD or HDD)
- Screen at least 14"

Optional

- Numpad
- Keyboard backlight
- USB 3.0 ports

Comment: Do you have a budget for this laptop? I could easily find one that fits your needs for over $1200 USD.

Comment: I don't have a budget limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lenovo IdeaPad Y50-70-59441231** meets your requirements.
A comprehensive review can be found [here](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-Y50-70-GTX-960M-4K-Notebook-Review.145340.0.html).
I am talking about model with GTX 960M. Price: 1499 Euro.

According to your spec:

- NVIDIA [GeForce GTX 960M](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-960M.138006.0.html) has 4096 MB GDDR5 memory - the same memory bandwidth as the previous GTX 860M, it has higher core clock and it leads to a slightly better performance. 960M is almost 10 percent faster and similar to the desktop GTX 750 Ti. Many games of 2014/2015 can be played fluently in FullHD resolution and high detail settings.
- Memory: up to 16 GB DDR3-1600, dual-channel, two memory banks
  http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-960M.138006.0.html
- Samsung SSD PM851 512 GB MZ7TE512HMHP, 512 GB. It is less than desired, but it can be easily replaced. Take the price into account - SSD are much more expensive.
- Display: 15.6 inch 16:9, 3840x2160 pixel, Samsung L FLLTN156FL02L01, IPS (glossy)
- There are three USB ports on this notebook, whereas two of them are USB 3.0 ports ([Source](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y50-70-59441231.141509.0.html))
- Numpad: Yes
- Backlight: Yes.

> The side shafts of the island-style keys are made of translucent red
>   plastic, and the light shines through the actual key bodies, rather
>   than simply leaking from around the key cutouts, as in other backlit
>   laptops. [Source](http://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-y50-touch/).

**Gaming Performance**

> Lenovo's Y50 is explicitly aimed at gamers. Thus,
>   it is not surprising that it can render all current games smoothly. It
>   is normally possible to select the Full HD resolution and high to very
>   high quality settings. The resolution and/or quality level has to be
>   reduced in some games, for example "The Witcher 3". The frame rates
>   are only slightly higher than that of laptops equipped with a GeForce
>   GTX 860M graphics core. However, the advantage over 860 models of the
>   Y50 is greater, like in the 3DMark benchmarks, because the GeForce GTX
>   860M GPUs in the Y50 models do not clock at their maximum possible
>   speeds.
>
> The screen's maximum resolution (3840 x 2160 pixels) can only be fully
>   utilized in rare cases. This option is at most possible in games that
>   only have moderate hardware requirements. The Y50 only achieves just
>   below 70 fps in the benchmark of the game "Dirt Rally" in very low
>   quality settings. The rates drop to 25.3 fps in medium and 22.8 fps in
>   high settings. [Source](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-Y50-70-GTX-960M-4K-Notebook-Review.145340.0.html).

[image: Photo from http://www.notebookcheck.net]

[Diablo III Reaper of Souls on Lenovo Y50-70 (with 860M).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-aaPUqZ2UE)

[image]

[image]